# How to sell/exit signal 1 bar delay

Tags: pine-script

how i can separete this both (sell and sell tp/sl) signals on the same bar ? I mean I would like to get sell signal onto the next bar. can i add 1 bar delay?

[image: strategy signals]

Comment: `strategy.exit(..., when = strategy.position_size!=0)` - the condition `strategy.position_size!=0` will be true on next bar after entry. This is what you need.